# Wine programs (Steam and Football Manager) don't work after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, wine

Since upgrading to Natty some programs using wine don't work.

- Steam
- Football Manager 2011

I've tried reinstalling and they both crash. I have tried Wine 1.3 and it still doesn't work.

I get the error:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/610185/

This is using wine version 1.2.

Comment: Unity and wine are unrelated. If the program is crashing on Wine, then it's likely that there are missing functions in a dll or something.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: Not really. They are related and may cause wine apps to crash in some cases. However, it's true, that crashing at start is unlikely to be caused by Unity.

Comment: @raalcieslak: how are they related? Is Unity directly proportional to WINE (as a matter of speaking)?

Comment: What made me think that it was something to do with unity is that I used the applications on a beta version natty and it worked ok. But on the full version it no longer worked I assumed it was unity as it went through some pretty major changes.

Comment: If you suspect it is a problem with Unity, you can logout, login to Ubuntu Classic (i.e. Gnome 2), and try it.

Comment: @elmicha Thanks thats a good idea. I'll try that when I get home from work.

Comment: Ok I've tried it in Ubuntu classic mode and still no dice. I get the same error. I'll try some directx 9 stuff to see if I can kickstart it.

Comment: This could be a bug, did you try to Google part of the error message? If you still don't find anything try filing a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it working.

If you get the error shown in the original post, find and save the listed .dll files to: `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32.`

- gameux.dll
- import.dll
- duser.dll

Comment: It's a little temperamental, after a few tries it seems to work though. It's good enough for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

Unity completely wrecks the Wine user experience in several important ways.

1. Compiz (desktop effects) is required, and Compiz often messes with Wine
2. The Application Lens does not show any subfolders or allow the user to filter by wine apps, making finding them in the big alphabetical mess of a list difficult.
3. Most Wine apps show the Wine icon rather than their icon in the dock.

This happened because Unity was not designed with Wine users in mind.  At all.  This is partially my fault, as I was a bit busy this cycle and should have been shouting from the rooftops to get Wine users noticed, but I was a bit busy with personal life and barely managed to get the system tray not intentionally broken.

That said, your specific application issue is probably not Unity-related.  I will be putting out a [new Wine1.2 release soon](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.2/+bug/771769) and issuing a stable release update for Natty, however in the meantime I would encourage you to try Wine1.3 ("Beta release" in Software Center) or the [Wine PPA](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the information. Unfortunately I still have the same error with the 1.3 beta.

Comment: Are you using proprietary 3d drivers?  If not (and you used to) that could be the source of the issue.  Also, the err: you see in the terminal might not be the source of the actual problem -- pasting a full terminal log on paste.ubuntu.com could be helpful.

Comment: I am using proprietary 3d drivers. Next week I'm going to do a full wipe and reinstall. I'll paste my terminal log in this evening. I'd really like this to get up and running.

Comment: Ok Scott I have uploaded a full terminal log. http://paste.ubuntu.com/610185/

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to the newer version of Wine (1.2.2) in Natty Narwhal. In Maverick Meerkat came with Wine version 1.2. It has nothing to do with Unity.

Comment: You can try Wine 1.3 from ubuntu-wine ppa: `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`. Chances are it will solve your problem.

Comment: @raalcieslak: this should be an answer.

Comment: to be honest I think the first thing I did was try 1.3 and still no dice. I might try and force 1.2 on there. See how it likes that. Cheers all.

Comment: I get the error: 'err:d3d:IWineD3DDeviceImpl_Reset Cannot change the back buffer count yet'

this is using wine version 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to disable the 3D somehow?

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21720

Comment: annoyingly, the 3D worked before. It just seemed strange that all of a sudden, it would stop working.